# "Look at the sun setting" OR "Look at the setting sun"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, participles

> Look at the **sun setting.**
>
> Look at the **setting sun.**

As far as I know, **setting** in the first sentence is a **participle** and in the second sentence it is an **adjective.**

Do they both mean the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Look at the sun setting.

You are instructing the person to observe the setting of the sun. "Setting" is a verb here.

> Look at the setting sun.

The sun is setting, and you are instructing the person the look at the sun. "Setting" is an adjective here.

Consider the following:

> Look at the man running.

We observe the running.

> Look at the running man.

We observe the man who is running (perhaps as opposed to other men), but we haven't been directly instructed to observe the action of running.

This clarifies the difference of meaning implied by the sentence structure.

However, given that there is (generally) only one sun, the two statements about the sun generally equate to the same thing, and would usually be used to point out the natural beauty of the sunset.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of both sentences is the same.